# div hover trigger isnt working with box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have an image, and a text-block on top of it, when I hover over either the image or the `text-block` I want the text-block to get a `box-shadow`.

**The problem** comes when I try to trigger the `text-block` from the image, it just doesn't seem to work especially with `box-shadow` yet with another attr like 
`color` it does trigger.

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x5Lr32xb/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="button-container">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="htmllogo" src="images/HTMLLogo.png">
                    <div class="html-text-block">
                        <h2>HTML</h2>
                        <p>My web projects</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="csharplogo" src="images/CSHARPLogo.png">
                    <div class="cs-text-block">
                        <h2>C#</h2>
                        <p>My windows projects</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Containers*/
#button-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;

    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;

    margin-top: 33vh;
    margin-left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 

    width: 90vw;
    height: 56vh;

    align-items: center;
}

#button-container li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

#button-container .html-text-block, .cs-text-block {    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}


/*Hovers*/
#button-container .html-text-block:hover, .cs-text-block:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

img:hover + .html-text-block {
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

Comment: why not use hover on <a>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
#button-container img:hover + .html-text-block
```

#button-container .html-text-block is more specified than just .html-text-block